# tf.GradientTape returning None for Grad-CAM

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradienttape

I'm trying to implement the following code to apply Grad-CAM to my model.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
   real_y = tf.expand_dims(y_test_ballest[0], axis=0)
   real_y = tf.reshape(real_y, shape=[1,1])
   #real_y = tf.Variable(real_y, trainable=True)

   value_x = x_test_ballest[0].reshape((-1, 41, 41, 1))
   pred_y = model_Ballest(value_x)
   model_loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(real_y, pred_y)
   #model_loss = tf.Variable(model_loss, trainable=True)
   conv_outputs = tf.Variable(gradModel(value_x), trainable=True)
model_gradients = tape.gradient(model_loss, conv_outputs)
```

Here:

```
y_test_ballest[0]
```

is a numpy.int32, with shape (), and

```
y_test_ballest[0]
```

is a numpy.ndarray of shape (41,41).

```
model_Ballest
```

is the complete model
[with the following structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p90oi.png), and

```
gradModel
```

is the same model as "model_Ballest" until the "max_pooling2D_5" layer. This model lacks of the last layers. In other words, the model only takes the first 5 layers of "model_Ballest" with their weights.

The inputs of "tape.gradient()" have the following attributes:

```
model_loss
>> <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([----], dtype=float32)>
```

and

```
conv_outputs
>> <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1, 8, 8, 32) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[[[----]]]])>
```

Here, the numpy arrays are real arrays but I skiped that data with "----" for the question.

Comment: Why are you defining a tf.Variable for conv_outputs? That is not necessary.

Comment: This Keras tutorial [Grad-CAM class activation visualization](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/) might help you. Note that the gradient with respect of the last convolutive layer is computed on a predicted class, not on the loss.

Comment: Thanks a lot elbe, that was part of the problem. Following the suggested tutorial helps to find the solution.